# Accessing and viewing contents of dtsx files

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a set of MS SQL 2005 packages (SSIS packages) that were created in Visual Studio 2005 that I need to be able to at least view.  I have been unsuccessful trying to view them in Visual Studio Community.  They were created with VS 2005 on a MS SQL 2005 server.

I have no experience in dealing with this type of programming (that I know of).  The packages were created by a former programmer that is no longer on the earth. No one has been able to view them to even see what they are doing.  We are in the middle of a crash and I can not think of a workaround for these DB jobs because I don't even know what they do.  Their is no documentation.  I need to be able to look at the packages to be able to see if what needs to be done as a work around.  Further more this has shown a huge issue in our support as moving forward we can not duplicate/re-write the code.

I am lost.

Comment: thank you for your response.  I was advised just to back them up and pray that nothing happens to them.  So that is what I am going to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Sql Server CD then install the BIDs tools from there onto a computer and that'll have everything you need to open up the DTSX.

Here's one such link that'll help you install BIDS.

http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2015/04/sql-server-data-tools-bids-visual-studio/

If you don't have a Sql server CD, the  download a community VS and the install the following: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313